# MySQL and PHP unicode problems

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I have the following UTF-8 file exported from a microsoft access file

http://www.yousendit.com/download/TTZtT214SU84Q1FLSkE9PQ

I have ensured my mysql database is utf8 with the status; command for both client and server. I insert the above file into my database with the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'tblAuction1.txt' INTO TABLE Auctions FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\';
```

All seems to be going kind of OK, unicode characters are displayed in the html as they should be as far as I can tell. The direct contents of the database field is here:

http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22622

However the resulting html code is displayed:

http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22617

Which displays as

Fee Listing

```
1.00 
<\/OBJECT>
');\n\t\t<\/SCRIPT>\n\t\t
```

in the browser

The code I am using to show this is:

http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22618

which was working fine before I changed the encoding.

as a side question, I am wondering why changing from tab delimited to semicolon delimited, and enclosing fields would ddecrease the size of the exported file by half. The tab character is a single character just like the ; character, and adding quotes to enclose should have increased the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the configuration of the web server you may need to explicitly set the encoding to "text/html; charset=UTF-8", with `header()`:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

This should be enough for your specific problem, but - in case you also intend to manipulate the strings - note that PHP contains many functions that are not safe to use with multi-byte characters: you should at least properly configure the [mbstring extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

I also have this [cheatsheet](http://www.nicknettleton.com/zine/php/php-utf-8-cheatsheet) in my bookmarks, I think it's still relevant.

Comment: That did not seem to fix anything, is it possibly a problem with the database? It seems to be a problem with the html meant to be passed to document.write, and a tag unclosed somewhere.

Comment: The unclosed tag is orthogonal to the UTF-8 encoding... I though you had issues displaying correctly the non-ASCII characters.